# How to split a URL into string array

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to be able to the URL of the current page and extract from the end to the last appearance of `/`

So for example, if my URL is this: `http://myintranet/guidelines/Home/Pages/mymed.aspx`

I want to extract `mymed`.

I have this so far:

```
string strEntity = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
Label2.Text = strEntity;
```

which displays:

```
/guidelines/Home/Pages/mymed.aspx
```

I tried to use `Split("\\").Last();` but that didn't work for it and said cannot assign string[] to string...

Comment: have you seen the `System.Uri` class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) method from the `System.IO.Path` class:

```
var uri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(uri.AbsolutePath);
```

Comment: +1, this is even better

Answer (score 4):

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://myintranet/guidelines/Home/Pages/mymed.aspx");
var segments = uri.Segments;
//do something with the array of segments
```

Edit: as noted, you don't need to create a Uri since you already have one:

```
var lastPart = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Segments.Last();
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I get the last segment? And that is using hard coded url but I want it to be dynamic.

Comment: `uri.Segments.Last();`

Answer (score 4):

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://myintranet/guidelines/Home/Pages/mymed.aspx");
var segments = uri.Segments;
var last = segments.Last(); //to get the last
var mymed = last.Split(".")[0]; //to separate the name from the extention
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
 var ub = new UriBuilder("http://myintranet/guidelines/Home/Pages/mymed.aspx");
 NameValueCollection nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(ub.Query);
 string page = nvc[nvc.Count - 1];
```

Comment: QueryString is empty in this case... you need the path, not the query string